# Searching particular words in mysql field and return the value

Tags: php, mysql, search

I need help guys! Let me give an example here... Let say I have this two entries in 'comment' field of mysql..

```
 Entry 01: Kindly contact me through my email address entry01@nobody.com

 Entry 02: Please drop an email to entry02@you.com for more information
```

And i wanted to pull out only the email address from the entries. Anybody would be able to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to do this? in PHP or MySQL?

Comment: in sql please... i just need to trigger the email address only, not the whole line in that particular entry

Comment: post your table structure

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM your_table 
  WHERE your_column_entry1 
  LIKE  '%nobody.com%' 
  OR your_column_entry2 LIKE '%you.com%'
```

Comment: or... use the MySQL `REGEXP` operator -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html.

Comment: @goodmood thanks for your help mr... but actually im trying to pull out the email only. not the whole line in that comment field.

Comment: There are a lot regex examples for matching emails, but I don't know how to convert it to something mysql can use.